# can you run wamp and IIS on the same server (win2k3)

Tags: iis, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IIS and Apache on same box?](https://serverfault.com/questions/43934/iis-and-apache-on-same-box)

I have a windows server 2003 box currently running a number of things off a wamp server (Cats, media wiki etc)

I created a new asp.net application and i would like to host it as well but I'm unsure how to host it with out stepping on the toes of the wamp side of things

any ideas if this can be done and if so how

Answer (score 1):

Yes see previous question [Here](https://serverfault.com/questions/43934/iis-and-apache-on-same-box)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use two different IP address or TCP ports for your two web servers; they won't be able to bind to the same IP and port.

You should configure both of them to listen only where they should; f.e., in IIS you need to disable or modify the *Default Web Site*, which, by default, listens on every available IP address on port 80.